# What is a reasonable bandwidth usage for a RT multiplayer game?

Tags: networking, google-play-services, udp, realtime

My game uses UDP communication only.
Meaning: after the lobby connect (performed by Google Play Services), not a single TCP transmission is made. Only [unreliable messages](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RealTimeMultiplayer#sendUnreliableMessage(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20byte[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) are used.

The game is currently one versus one, and the players transmit a little over 16Kbit/sec in datagrams in a steady stream. (2 kbyte/sec.)
It also receives the same steady 16kbit/sec from the other party of course.
These numbers do not include packet headers.

The player experience is pretty good, even with players between continents.

What I would like to know: is 16Kbit/sec considered normal, high or low?

I intend to add a 2vs2 mode, which would triple both the send and receive network volume. Could I get away with that? Where can I find references to typical bandwidth use in real time games?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this article, I would say 100MByte/hour is a reasonable estimate for the popular multiplayer games out there:

https://www.rhoonet.com/how-much-data-does-online-gaming-use

100MByte/hour converts to 28.4KByte/sec, which is 228KBit/sec.  Therefore your current usage of 16KBit/sec is definitely acceptable, even if you were to triple it.